# JavaScript: Invalid left-hand side in assignment?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner and I want to make color game as a project. The html contains six grids but the javascript is showing the error?

```
var colors = [
 "rgb (255, 0, 0)",
 "rgb (255, 255, 0)",
 "rgb (255, 0, 255)",
 "rgb (0, 255, 255)",
 "rgb (0, 255, 0)",
 "rgb (0, 0, 255)",
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
 squares[i].style.background-color = colors[i];
}
```

Comment: `style.background-color` is invalid syntax for accessing a property name with dashes in it

Comment: This question is not duplicated completely as there is error in `colors` array where the style will not apply as there is white space in `rgb (255, 0, 0)` after `rgb` which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- There should not be any white space in `rgb (255, 0, 0)`. The color value should be `rgb(255, 0, 0)` where there is no space after `rgb`
- Second issue is the `background-color` which should be `backgroundColor`.

```js
var colors = [
 "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
 "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
 "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
 "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
 squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

```html
<div class='square'>Color 1</div>
<div class='square'>Color 2</div>
<div class='square'>Color 3</div>
<div class='square'>Color 4</div>
<div class='square'>Color 5</div>
<div class='square'>Color 6</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to vote but can not because I am a noob.

Answer (score 1):

It is throwing an error because style.background-color has a dash in it and it is not valid . You can use background instead

```
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
 squares[i].style.background  = colors[i];
}
```

or backgroundColor as follows,

```
 squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
```

Comment: or `backgroundColor` if needing to modify the color only

Comment: @PatrickEvans yeah